# QGIS symbology: where are simple markers located in the system?

Tags: qgis, symbology, svg

I would like to know, where are simple svg-markers (for example the one that is defined as "regular_star" in `.qml` file) are physically located in the system? I searched the system and looked inside the `symbology-ng-style.db`, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symbol references are stored in `symbology-ng-style.db` in table `symbol`. But the name in column `name` is not what is shown as symbol label in style dialogs.

The name *regular_star* is defined as value of property `name` in the xml symbol definition in column `xml`.

[image: styles in db]

Look at the xml definition (double click on the cell with xml content):

[image: xml style definition]

These symbols are hard coded in the Qgis sources. See this snipped from file `qgsmarkersymbollayerv2.cpp`:

[image: src of regular_star]

Comment: I feared that this is the case... Is there any way to export them to SVG?

Comment: Hmm. The hard coding seems to extend graphical primitives of Qt. All style properties are parameterized outside, eg in these xml stories. When you take Inkscape you also have a set of primitives, which you can export to svg and then use in QGIS as symbols. But the strange thing is: my own SVG symbol cannot be changed in QGIS (eg fill color), as is the case with the provided symbols.

Comment: Just delete all attributes from `<path .../>` element except the geometry description and added `fill="param(fill)" stroke="param(outline)" stroke-width="param(outline-width)"`, and it works: fill color, border width and color can be changed in QGIS style properties.

Answer (score 0):

I found the .svg symbols in the QGIS program folder by searching for .svg. On my system, for 3 different QGIS versions, the .svg files for the symbol options were located in `C:\Program Files\~QGIS Version~\apps\qgis\svg\`. I usually add a custom folder and put my own .svg symbols in there.